# .NET Timespan object: How do I get the Start and End DateTime?

Tags: .net

Consider this:

```
Dim StartDate As DateTime = #06/12/2010 6:32PM#
Dim EndDate As DateTime = #06/13/2010 10:47PM#
Dim ElapsedSpan As TimeSpan = StartDate - EndDate
```

Does the TimeSpan object retain the original Start and End datetimes that make up the span period? It doesn't appear to and only seems to store the amount of time elapsed not the actual end points.

If I want this too, should I create my own class, I suppose or is there a better object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure. This does almost what you want.

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` is to be used to represent a single point of time, not two points in time. The constructor will also throw exceptions if you would try to abuse it because the maximum offset is 14 hours. The primary use for `DateTimeOffset` is to record and transfer date with timezone offset information. Think of it as a UTC date with the additional information of the offset that the date uses to UTC.

Answer (score 8):

No, TimeSpan is a single measurement of an amount of time, not a specific start and end time.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct, timespan does not store anything dealing with the original dates as you used them above.  The only reason you get a timespan with that is that the - operator is overloaded for datetime to return a timespan.  I don't know of any class that would do this for you.